# Font awesome in Ruby on Rails Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I am using Font-Awesome in my ruby on rails project and I am also using the Slim html pre-processor. I am having trouble getting font-awesome to work and I know it is just an issue of me being new to Slim

Here is what I am attempting to do in HTML

```
<a href="#" class="hollow-btn-green">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

In my Slim file, I was thinking it would be something along the lines of this:

```
a.hollow-btn-green href="#" Sign Up
  i.fa.fa-arrow-right
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. It just outputs the literal i.fa.fa-arrow-right into the button instead of processing that to the html code.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is the `Sign Up` text not being escaped from formatting. Try this:

```
a.hollow-btn-green href="#"
    |Sign Up 
    i.fa.fa-arrow-right
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I hope this will help.

```
=link_to "#", class: "hollow-btn-green"
  |Sign Up
  i.fa.fa-arrow-right
```

Comment: This will cause the `sign-Up` text to go after the `fa` element

Comment: almost there). This would return "up" in the view, because the "Sign" part will be treated as a tag. I would add the `|` symbol (see my answer), to make sure it gets rendered as plain text.